# How to make a select that combines various results from different wheres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres as db.

I have a select that brings a total billing of a certain period.

```
SELECT SUM(vend_vtotal) 
FROM venda 
where vend_data >= ? and vend_data <= ?;
```

Ex:

```
SELECT SUM(vend_vtotal) 
FROM venda 
where vend_data >= '01-08-19' 
and vend_data <= '31-08-19';
```

Returns total August billing

If I want to know the annual invoicing (maker a chart with all monthly invoices) could I make 12 selects? Could .... What I want to know is if there is any way to make a single select that returns me several fields with monthly billings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for aggregation?

```
select date_trunc('month', vend_data) as mon, sum(vend_vtotal) as total
from venda v
where vend_data >= '2019-01-01' and vend_data < '2020-01-01'
group by date_trunc('month', vend_data)
order by mon;
```